# How to prepopulate input text fields with prompting text which disappears on typing (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

When you click on the `"Ask Question"` button on Stack Overflow, the question title section is prepopulated with light gray text that reads

```
"what's your programming question? be specific"
```

Then when you click inside the Title field and start typing, that text disappears.

I want to do the same thing in my app.

Is there a trick in jQuery to accomplish that?

**And, specifically, how do you change the text color from light gray for the placeholder text to the default text color when someone starts typing?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is with html (albeit html5)'s `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address." name="email" />
```

It will appear as "lighter colored" text that disappears when the user starts entering something.

However, if you really want/need to use jQuery (as the above html-solution is only usable in the more modern/compliant browsers), here's a way:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:text').each(
            function(){
                $(this).click(
                    function(){
                        $(this).val('');
                    });
                $(this).blur(
                    function(){
                        if ($(this).val == '') {
                            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
                        }
                    });
            });
    });
```

---

**Edited** to add a missing `)` in the final `if`, and also to add a slightly revised version of the above that features slightly greyed-out `placeholder` text (as I assume the OP would like, given his question in the comments, below):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:text').each(
            function(){
                $(this)
                    .val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
                    .css('color','#999');
                $(this).click(
                    function(){
                        $(this)
                            .val('')
                            .css('color','#000');
                    });
                $(this).blur(
                    function(){
                        if ($(this).val() === ''){
                            $(this)
                                .val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
                                .css('color','#999');
                        }
                    });
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9BpGC/).

Comment: Would this make the placeholder text a lighter color than the text that is typed?

Comment: It depends on the browser's implementation, **usually** (at least with Chrome 7.0.517.44, and Firefox 3.6.12) `placeholder` text is rendered in a lighter colour. I'm unsure of IE or Opera's implementation, however.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" value="whats your programming question" id="txt"/>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txt').click(function(){
          this.value = '';
          this.style.color = 'black';
    }).blur(function(){
      if ( this.value == '')
          this.value = 'whats your programming question';
           this.style.color = 'lightgray';
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like it just about covers it except for the issue of changing the text color from light gray for the placeholder text to the default text color when someone starts typing. Do you know how that is accomplished?

Comment: yeah i edited the response above, just play with the style properties, you can change the css class too which is a better approach if the style differ more than just with the color

Answer (score 4):

The solutions presented so far have a drawback: the prompted text is submitted to the server if the user doesn't enter any value in the input. You can find here a better solution that also takes care of this issue:
http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/input-prompt-text/

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't know how to do it in jQuery, it's pretty simple to do so directly with JavaScript. Just assign a function that clears the text field on the onClick property of the field, like so:

```
<input type="text" id="textID" onclick="clear" />
```

And you Java script would be something like:

```
function clear()
{
    document.getElementById("textID").value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are great starting points, the user can then check for the promptext value on submit and ignore it (or not submit if it is still there, etc)

I had a lot of trouble getting the http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/input-prompt-text/ solution working re getting the prompt text to line up with the input box in every browser tested