# text box with placeholder text that dissapears character by character

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to structure a textbox with placeholder text for a date field. The placeholder text would be xx/xx/xxxx and disappear character by character leaving the slashes in place as the user types.  I came across the following two questions which seem to solve the problem of making the text disappear all at once.

[HTML/CSS Making a textbox with text that is grayed out, and disappears when I click to enter info, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681036/html-css-making-a-textbox-with-text-that-is-grayed-out-and-disappears-when-i-cl)

[How to prepopulate input text fields with prompting text which disappears on typing (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289025/how-to-prepopulate-input-text-fields-with-prompting-text-which-disappears-on-typ)

I am wondering if maybe there is a javascript trick or something that could accomplish this.