# How to make placeholder disappear character by character when typing in input tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an input tag with 6 dots kind of placeholder role like below:

[image]

If I type 9, one of dots disppears as per the position taken by 9 just typed.

It is **not** like the behavior of placeholder attribute that something typed the whole text or dots set as placeholder disappear at one go. Once again I wanted to make it disappear **one by one**.

That ideally looking like below:

[image]

And if I type number and hit the backspace button to delete it the dot will surely be back to the position.

I found one [Placeholder that disappears character by character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071679/placeholder-that-disappears-character-by-character) but unfortunately, I must use input tag not div or span like the given link.

I was wondering is there a way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I eventually got it disappeared when typing but not too sure to bring back the dots when deleting user inputs.

Here's my attempt below or a brief reproductino on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/verification-number-input-4f25l?file=/src/VerificationNumberInput.tsx

```
// VerificationInput.tsx

const dotElement = <Dot
    width='11'
    height='11'
    viewBox='0 0 20 20'
    color='#e0e0e0'
  />;
  
  const [dots, setDots] = useState(Array(4).fill(dotElement));
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {}, [dots]);

  const handleDots = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      // remove dots when typing
      setInputValue(event.target.value);
      const copiedDots = [...dots];
      copiedDots.splice(0, 1);
      setDots(copiedDots);
   
      // logic to bring dots back again when userinput deleted
      // ???
  };

...

<div className='card-num__full'>
<input
  type='tel'
  autoComplete='on'
  maxLength={4}
  className='card-num__field'
  value={inputValue}
  onChange={handleDots}
  {...args}
/>

<div>
  {dots.map((d) => d)}
</div>
</div>
```

```
// css

.card-num__full {
  position: relative;
  width: 56px;
  height: 22px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

input.card-num__field {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  width: 56px;
  height: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: i think you have to use the `::before` tag for the input tag and use it as a placeholder for your input, and then try changing it for every letter in input tag using js. i know it sounds complicated, but i found somewhere using `::before` for a input tag as a placeholder and thats what im trying to say, i think you get it what i mean...

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing implemented with a input element for each digit. It was for entering a verification number sent in a sms. Here's an example from codepen: https://codepen.io/RobertAron/pen/gOLLXLo

Comment: Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output. This gives people a place to help you implement your feature, rather than implementing it for you.

Comment: @Håken Lid it is actually input for verification number sent by sms.

Comment: @footlessbird Can you provide a codesandbox link?

Comment: @pilchard
Here's brief reproduction on codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/verification-number-input-4f25l?file=/src/VerificationNumberInput.tsx

Comment: @TechySharnav
https://codesandbox.io/s/verification-number-input-4f25l?file=/src/VerificationNumberInput.tsx