# Form value to be empty if no change by user

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I have a form with two inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" value="Search" onfocus="wipe(this)"/>
<input type="text"  name="city" value="City" onfocus="wipe(this)"/>
```

and my JavaScript which gets rid of the pre-set value in form field as soon as you click it with your mouse is:

```
function wipe(obj)
{
obj.value="";
}
```

My question is, say the user doesn't type anything in the city field, how do I make it so that when the form is submitted the value for that field is empty and not the word City?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**placeholder**  is a good attribute which can solve your problem its a past time history when we are used to using value for showing for which this textbox we have

```
 <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search" />
```

if you still want to use java script modify your code something like this

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" value="Search" onfocus="wipe(this,'Search')" onblur="wipe2(this,'Search')"/>
<input type="text"  name="city" value="City" onfocus="wipe(this,'City')" onblur="wipe2(this,'City')"/>
```

script function for second approch

```
function wipe(obj, str)
{
if(obj.value!=str){
obj.value="";}
}

function wipe2(obj, str)
{if(obj.value==""){
obj.value=str;}
}
```

Comment: let me know this is helpfull for you or not

Comment: hi. yes this is great thanks, i couldn't get the jquery to work in the anwser i approved above.

Comment: is placeholder safe to use? or is it better practice to go with the javascript?

Comment: place holder safe to use its only not work in some old browsers , lan where are you stuck in jquery

Comment: wait, the onblur bit doesnt work. im just going to use placeholder

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute doesn't work in IE below version 10. [There are polyfills](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) that will allow it to work in all main browsers though, so it's safe to use along with one of those.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong technique here.  you should be using [placeholder](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) which is [supported by most major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder) with the regular exception of IE. So if this is not a concern for you, you should definitely be using that. Especially, if you have a label element for that field.  Otherwise you'd need to be checking for that input value on submission and see if it equals the string city

Comment: @rahul I mentioned that in my answer, but for most situations that is a good tradeoff.

Comment: you can use it with IE, there is js library for it.

Comment: @dividebyzero yes, you can use http://www.modernizr.com/ for that, but I would not pull this whole library just for placeholder though, it's a judgement call though

Comment: Modernizr won't polyfill the attribute, it will just detect support for it. I have written a [non-jQuery polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) that will add `placeholder` support to all main browsers, including IE6.

Answer (score 1):

at the time of submit why not check for `value='city'`

```
if(obj.value!='city')
{
    //your code here
}
```

or if you have no problem in using jquery use watermark plugin this will handle browser compatibility problem also

[Jquery Watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)

Answer (score 1):

Just Declare a variable hasChanged and set it true when wipe function is called.Then call a  function say 'SubmitFunction()'on the onclick function of Submit button.

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" value="Search" id="Search" onfocus="wipe(this)"/>
<input type="text"  name="city" value="City" id="City" onfocus="wipe(this)"/>
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit"  onclick="SubmitFunction();"/>
var hasChanged=false;
function wipe(obj)
 {
  hasChanged=true;
  obj.value="";
 }
function SubmitFunction()
 {
 if(hasChanged==false)
  {

   $("#City").val('');
  }
 }
```

Comment: Lots of great anwsers from everyone. my simple brain understands this one best (after just using placeholders).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if($('input[name="city"]').val() && $('input[name="city"]').val() != 'city') { yourform.submit(); }
```

Comment: well this is a jquery answer and question tages not contains jquery

Answer (score 0):

See [How to prepopulate input text fields with prompting text which disappears on typing (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289025/how-to-prepopulate-input-text-fields-with-prompting-text-which-disappears-on-typ) for some solutions to this.  If you're okay with using HTML5, the best solution is probably to use "placeholder" instead of "value".

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more attribute(eg. default `<input type="text" name="keyword" default="Search" value="Search" onfocus="wipe(this)"/>`) with value same as value attribute.

in on submit compare each form fields

```
function onSubmit(){
    for (var fields in form)
      if(form[fields].value== form[fields].getAttribute("default")){
          form[fields].value = "";
      }
   }
}
```